# Move wrapfigure figure further right

Tags: spacing, floats, wrapfigure

I wish to move my figure outside the margin boundaries shown beneath.

BEFORE:
[image: Image Before]

DESIRED OUTPUT:
[image]

My current code is detailed beneath.

```
\begingroup
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
  \caption{Sidebar menu detailed view.}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{close-up-menu.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}

lispum[1]
\endgroup
```

Any help is appreciated. I am also not to happy with the spacing between the image and text. How would I go about moving the figure over, whilst also increasing the spacing between the image and text? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[2cm]{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
  \caption{Sidebar menu detailed view.}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{close-up-menu.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

[2cm] moves the picture outside
0.8\linewidth reduces the picture inside the box.

François

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I do not wish for the image to reduce in size, just the spacing between the text/fig to be slightly larger

Comment: So: increase the width of wrapfigure. For example: \begin{wrapfigure}{r}|2cm]{0.60\textwidth} \includegraphics[width=0.917\linewidth]{close-up-menu} \end{wrapfigure}